# How can I constrain search result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to constrain the result by genre_id which is the column in Communities table.
But the end of the line in communities_controller says error.
Why? How can I fix this?

**communities_controller.rb**

```
        @search = Community.search do  
            fulltext params[:search]
            paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 5
        end 

        @communities = @search.results

        @communities = @communities.find_by_genre_id(params[:genre])
```

Comment: My guess is @communities is not an active record, which means you can't do a "find_by_genre_id" on it, which is likely why it is failing.

Comment: how can I constrain with the criteria written in question then??

Comment: What are you using to search? Some gem or something? Is `@search.results` an array?

Comment: Also please post the error you get.

Comment: You should be able to include a constraint on the genre_id column in your .search block. I've never used that gem that you're using though so I can't say for certain

Comment: `find_by_genre_id` is a class method, so you can't call it on an instance. If you have an activerecord relation object, then you could call `scoped_by_genre_id`, but I think what you probably have is an array.

Comment: @shioyama I'm using sunspot

Comment: @shioyama I get this error **undefined method `find_by_genre_id' for #<Array:0x0000001127dda8>**

Comment: @cat exactly what I thought. I'll post an answer.

Comment: Just to check, what if you just add `with :genre_id, params[:genre]` inside the `Community.search do ... end` block (i.e. after the `paginate` line)?

Comment: @shioyama is it in new line?

Comment: If I put it in new line it returns this error **Sunspot::UnrecognizedFieldError No field configured for Community with name 'genre_id'**

Comment: In your model, you should have a `searchable` block. In there you need to add a line with `integer :genre_id`. Then I think it should work (although I've never used sunspot before!).

Comment: @shioyama thanks. dmoss18 answered already. But thanks anywayz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should watch this video: http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot

It will help you.

Here is the sample code he uses:
Model: article.rb

```
searchable do
  text :name, :boost => 5
  text :content, :publish_month
  text :comments do
    comments.map(&:content)
  end
  time :published_at
  string :publish_month
end

def publish_month
  published_at.strftime("%B %Y")
end
```

Search algorithm:

```
@search = Article.search do
    fulltext params[:search]
    with(:published_at).less_than(Time.zone.now)
    facet(:publish_month)
    with(:publish_month, params[:month]) if params[:month].present?
  end
  @articles = @search.results
```

I am not familiar with sunspot, but it looks like your error (unrecognized field) might be resolved by including :genre_id in your model, like this:

```
searchable do
  integer :genre_id
  ...
end
```

So your new search would look something like:

```
@search = Community.search do  
  fulltext params[:search]
  with(:genre_id, params[:genre_id])
  paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 5
 end
```